# Two size of head notes in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to replicate a saxophone score that use two sizes for head notes. Also it is needed to delete the brace symbol. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixjt
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
    \input musixjt
    \begin{center}
    \Bigtype Legato Duet\\[1ex]
    %\medtype Variación 30 de las Variaciones Goldberg para Clavier
    \end{center}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \parindent0mm
    \setinterstaff{1}{14}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setstaffs{1}{2}
    \generalmeter{\meterC}
    \nobarnumbers
    \startpiece 
    \znotes|\zcharnote{q}{\hspace*{-0.31cm}\bf Andante}\en%\tinynotesize \normalnotesize
    \Notes\zcharnote{u}{\hspace*{-2.26cm} \huge{{\A\bfseries\large 51}}}\cmidstaff\mf\zcharnote{o}{\ding{72}}\hsk\zcharnote{w}{\icresc}\isluru0n\zqu e\qu h\ibu0h{-2}\zqb0{f}\qb0{_i}\zqb0e\tbu0\qb0h\zqu g\qu j\zql i\curve {3}33\tslur0l\ql l\zcharnote{w}{\loff\tcresc}|\hsk\isluru0j\ql j\ibl0i{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0j\ql l\tslur0n\ql n\en\bar
    \Notes\zcharnote{w}{\icresc}\isluru0m\zhl j\hl m\zql l\tslur0o\ql o\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.38cm} \cbreath}}\hsk\zql k\ql n\zcharnote{w}{\loff\tdecresc}|\isluru0o\hl o\tslur0n\ql n\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.38cm} \cbreath}}\hsk\ql n\en\bar
    \notes\isluru0m\zql j\ql m\hsk\zqu g\qu j\hsk\hsk\hsk\curve {3}33\tslur0m\zhl j\hl m|\isluru0l\ql l\hsk\ibl0o{-2}\qb0{o}\tqb0n\ibl0l{0}\qb0{ljm}\curve {5}33\tslur0l\tqb0l\en\bar
    \Notes\zcharnote{w}{\icresc}\isluru0o\zqlp l\qlp o\zcl j\tslur0m\ql m\hsk\zhl i\hl l\hsk\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.16cm} \cbreath}}\zcharnote{w}{\loff\tdecresc}|\isluru0n\qlp n\tslur0l\cl l\hsk\hl k\hsk\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.16cm} \cbreath}}\en\bar
    \Notes\zcharnote{w}{\icresc}\isluru0l\zql i\ql l\ibl0g{2}\zqb0{g}\qb0{j}\zqb0h\tbl0\qb0k\zql i\ql l\zql j\curve {3}33\tslur0m\ql m\zcharnote{w}{\loff\tcresc}|\isluru0k\ql k\ibl0i{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0j\ql k\tslur0l\ql l\en
    \endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output should be as follow (note that the bass part has two sizes for note head):
[image: desired]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You say "Duet", but you use `\instrumentnumber{1}`, which should be 2. Then, according to the manual, there is no curled bracket (which is the standard to combine staffs of one instrument).
2. Your code shows that you use two stems, instead of producing cords according to the manual (paragraph 4.2)
3. You should be familiar with smallnotesize and tinynotesize. With `\zq e{\tinynotesize\off{0.37\elemskip}{\qu h}}` you get quite a reasonable result for the first group. The `\off` is not needed for tinynotes with the stem at the left: `{\tinynotesize\zq l}\ql i`. If the stem length does suit you, you can adjust it (with `\stemlength{6}`) but then you need to undo this every time with `\enotes`. Maybe you can define a macro for all this. With Splitting the lower cords in one voice with stem up and the second with stem down, would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

After implement Peters comments, the result code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixjt

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \input musixjt
    \begin{center}
    \Bigtype Legato Duet\\[1ex]
    %\medtype Variación 30 de las Variaciones Goldberg para Clavier
    \end{center}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \parindent0mm
    \setinterstaff{1}{14}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    %\setstaffs{1}{2}
    \generalmeter{\meterC}
    \nobarnumbers
    \startpiece 
    \znotes&\zcharnote{q}{\hspace*{-0.31cm}\bf Andante}\en%\tinynotesize \normalnotesize
    \Notes\zcharnote{u}{\hspace*{-2.26cm} \huge{\textcircled{\A\bfseries\large 51}}}\cmidstaff{\loffset{-2.1}{\mf}}\loffset{-1.3}{\zcharnote{o}{\ding{72}}}\hsk&\hsk\en
    \Notes\zcharnote{w}{\icresc}\isluru1l\zqu e{\tinynotesize\off{0.525\elemskip}{\qu h}}&\isluru0j\ql j\en
    \Notes\ibu0h{-2}\zqb0{f}{\tinynotesize\off{0.0\elemskip} \qb0{_i}}&\ibl1i{2}\qb1{i}\en
    \Notes\zqb0e\tbu0{\tinynotesize\off{0.0\elemskip} \qb0h}&\tqb1j\en
    \Notes\zqu g{\tinynotesize\off{-0.065\elemskip} \qu j}&\ql l\en
    \Notes\zql i\curve {3}33\tslur1l{\tinynotesize \ql l}\zcharnote{w}{\loff\tcresc}&\tslur0n\ql n\en\bar
    %1era Línea - 2do Compás 
    \Notes\loffset{2.2}{\zcharnote{w}{\icresc}}\isluru1m\zhl j{\stemlength{3}\tinynotesize\off{-0.547\elemskip} \hl m}&\isluru0o\hl o\en
    \notes\hsk\zql l\tslur1o{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \ql o}&\hsk\tslur0n\ql n\en
    \Notes\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.6cm} \cbreath}}\hsk&\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.6cm} \cbreath}}\hsk\en
    \Notes\zql k{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \ql n}\zcharnote{w}{\loff\tdecresc}&\ql n\en\bar
    %1era Línea - 3er Compás 
    \notes\isluru1m\zql j{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \ql m}&\isluru0l\ql l\en
    \notes\hqsk\zqu g{\tinynotesize\off{-0.06\elemskip} \qu j}&\ibl0o{-2}\qb0{o}\tqb0n\en
    \notes\qsk\curve {3}33\tslur1m\zhl j{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \hl m}&\ibl0l{0}\qb0{ljm}\curve {4}33\tslur0l\tqb0l\en\bar
    %1era Línea - 4to Compás
    \Notes\zcharnote{w}{\icresc}\isluru1o\zqlp l{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \qlp o}&\isluru0n\qlp n\en
    \Notes\zcl j\tslur1m{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \ql m}\hsk&\tslur0l\cl l\hsk\en
    \Notes\zhl i{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \hl l}\hsk\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.16cm} \cbreath}}\zcharnote{w}{\loff\tdecresc}&\hl k\hsk\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.16cm} \cbreath}}\en\bar
    %1era Línea - 5to Compás 
    \Notes\zcharnote{w}{\icresc}\isluru1l\zql i{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \ql l}&\isluru0k\ql k\en
    \Notes\ibl2g{2}\zqb2{g}{\tinynotesize\off{-0.6\elemskip} \qb2{j}}&\ibl0i{2}\qb0{i}\en
    \Notes\zqb2h\tbl2{\tinynotesize\off{-0.6\elemskip} \qb2{k}}&\tqb0j\en
    \Notes\zql i{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \ql l}&\ql k\en
    \Notes\zql j\tslur1m{\tinynotesize\off{-0.58\elemskip} \ql m}\zcharnote{w}{\loff\tcresc}&\tslur0l\ql l\en
    \endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

The solved output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Comment: You did not implement my second point and still work with two stems, which results in a visible double stem. Moreover, your offset is not the same with every note, for a part, because you work with spaces before the second note of a chord. Your last bar is not connected to the lines, probably due to the same reason. Third point: you should not post the implementation of other person's answer as your own answer and then accept it as the right answer, andcertainly not without have tidied up the entire score and having solved all problems.

Comment: Can you give a basic code example for your item two: "Your code shows that you use two stems, instead of producing cords according to the manual"?

Comment: I did under point 3: first a non spacing note head, e.g. \zq h, and then a spacing note head with stem \qu e, or: \zq l\ql i. For textual explanation see e.g. the lower part of paragraph 1.1.3 of the manual.